MFA with Azure B2C Custom Policies - getting redirected back to policy after login, and asked for MFA prompt again
I'm using Azure B2C Custom Policies with SMS 2FA via the PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify Technical profile. This works, but users are finding they're quite often, upon successful login, then immediately redirected back into the B2C login profile again and prompted for the 2FA code a second time (just 2FA this second time, not the username/password). This doesn't happen all the time, and seems to happen more often for some than others.
But I do have a way of reproducing it... if in my application (I'm using Blazor WASM with the RemoteAuthenticatorView component) I explicitly visit /authentication/login when I'm already successfully logged in - then it does the same thing (ie. redirects me to B2C with a 2FA prompt).
The XML I'm using is just taken from here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/SignUpOrSignin.xml
It feels like some kind of persistence issue with the isActiveMFASession claim. But I can't see anything in my XML that's different to the above-linked sample XML.
There's no obvious way to debug this either. The policies are set to write B2C logs to App Insights, but the logs are pretty meaningless and don't give any clues. Does anyone have any ideas to what could cause this, or suggestions on how to debug this?

It's because I was missing a required output claim in the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile.
I found it mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/69770/mfa-session-doesnt-work-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy
Search for an answer by 'Taeke Kooiker', where he says...

I've seen the same behavior and added the following line to the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId:
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />.
The issue is that the session manager relies on the Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber, which is not set when reading data from the directory. I've raised this issue last year in the advisors group, but haven't seen a follow up.

